# UK landside visa queries

Tags: visas, uk, transit, london

I am planning to travel from Chicago to Delhi via London with intention of ~36 hrs in transit.

I am Indian resident, with valid US visa (until 2015).

Going by UK border agency information [here](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/transitthroughtheuk/visa-to-transit-landside/) I will be needing land side visa.

I have following queries:

1. Is it possible to get the land side visa **on arrival** or do I need to apply prior to leaving US?
2. If it is on arrival, and for some reason I am denied, will I need to wait for connecting flight within airport for that long?
3. What is the procedure and fees? I scanned through the UK border agency site, but could not find a procedure, and further details. It seems very scattered.
4. I see that one of the flight option has 48 hrs 15 min difference. Can landside visa be applied for this case?