# Travelling from India to Canada: Transit visa in the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, transit

I will be traveling from India to Canada via United Kingdom in British Airways flight. The stopover in London is for 6 hours. I will be staying in the airport only. Do I need a transit visa for United Kingdom?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a visa for Canada (which you should to be able to fly there), you are exempted from the direct airside transit visa requirement, as explained on the [gov.uk website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no). The rules for transit to Canada are the same than for US-bound travelers so [the answers to this earlier question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9926/london-heathrow-airport-do-i-need-a-transit-visa) apply.

Comment: I have a visa for Canada. If my luggage is through, then i need not pass the UK border control. Right ??

Comment: @Arindam Exactly. No need.