# Baggage check through and transit visa requirements for Dubai and London

Tags: air-travel, transit-visas, emirates, air-canada, air-india

I'm from India and travelling from New Delhi to Calgary with two stopovers: at Dubai and London Heathrow. I have booked my journey on a single ticket but multiple airlines:

New Delhi to Dubai -  India
Dubai to London - Emirates
London to Calgary - Air Canada

I am confused whether my baggage will be checked through to my final destination or would I have to recheck-in during the stopover.

Also if I recheck-in my baggage in Dubai or London would I require a transit visa in that case?

I have a valid visa for Canada.

Comment: I would ask Air India about whether the luggage will be checked to which airport.  I would check government web sites for information about transit visa requirements.  Have you tried any of that?  (I believe your Canadian visa exempts you from the UK transit visa requirement, but I am not certain.)

Answer (score 3):

As you have a single ticket with all three airlines, then you should be OK for checking your bags through to Canada.  But the best bet is to double check with Air India to make sure they have Interline Agreements with Emirates (they should have with Air Canada as both are part of Star Alliance).

Assuming the Interline agreements are in place and your bags are checked through, then you need not clear immigration or customs at the intermediate airports.

With a Canadian Visa you are exempt from the UK's transit visa rules -  [Travelling from India to Canada: Transit visa in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27714/travelling-from-india-to-canada-transit-visa-in-the-uk).

Dubai offers a 96 hour transit visa, but if you are staying airside for only a few hours, I believe you do not need a visa.  Air India can likely confirm this when you check with them about the Interline Agreement.

Comment: actually, OP is flying Emirates, not Etihad.

Comment: Has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

### Luggage

Your best bet for information about luggage handling will be to ask the airline you will be checking in with.

### UK transit visa

According to https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa:

**Transiting without a visa**

You might be eligible for ‘transit without visa’ if:

- you arrive and depart by air
- have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you arrive
- have the right documents for your destination (eg a visa for that country)

**One of the following must also apply:**

- you’re travelling to (or on part of a reasonable journey to) Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA and have a valid visa for that country
- [other items omitted]

### Dubai transit visa:

According to http://www.uaeinteract.com/travel/visas.asp:

**Transit Visa**

Transit passengers stopping at Dubai International Airport for a minimum of 8 hours are eligible for a 96-hour transit visa. A valid onward ticket is required

Passports or travel documents must be valid for at least three months.

Citizens of the following countries are not eligible for the 96-hour visa on arrival:
Somalia, Afghanistan, Iraq, Niger, and Yemen.

Transit visas for passengers arriving at Dubai and Abu Dhabi International Airports can be arranged by Emirates Airline and Etihad Airways for their passengers or by Marhaba Services for those travelling on other airlines. Marhaba Services Tel: 00971 4 2162657; 2164629
email: marhaba@emirates.com