# Transit visa reqd for Heathrow? going to USA

Tags: usa, london, lhr, american-airlines

I am going on 6th Aug to Gainesville, FLorida, USA. My flight itinerary is as follows:
Mumbai to Heathrow - Jet Airways, Heathrow to Miami - American and Miami to Gainesville - American. Transit time at Heathrow is 3 hours. I will be arriving at Terminal 4 and will be departing at Terminal 3. Since Jet and American have a codeshare I guess my baggage will continue checked in and i dont think I have to recheck it. I have a valid F1 visa. Do I need a transit visa? PLs help.

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9926/london-heathrow-airport-do-i-need-a-transit-visa?rq=1 and many earlier related questions. Did you search the site before asking? How is your situation different?

Comment: Is this a single itinerary or multiple tickets?

Comment: @Relaxed i am changing terminals.. have viewd the qsn u pinned. in that changing terminals has not been mentioned abpout. so do i need a transit visa or not I am confused...

Comment: @Karlson single itinerary

Comment: You could maybe ask a separate question highlighting this issue, something like “Is it possible to stay airside when changing terminals at Heathrow”. I think there are busses that allow you to do it but I can't find an authoritative source to confirm that.

Comment: [This page from Heathrow airport's official website](http://www.heathrowairport.com/heathrow-airport-guide/flight-connections/terminal-4-international-connecting-to-terminal-3-international) does not explicitly mention visas but it would include the immigration check if there was one so it does imply you should be able to transit without visa.

Comment: Changing terminals doesn't matter, as Heathrow operates airside terminal transfer busses.